# Laravel create method returning null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have this problem. I have a Group and Role models, with a Many-to-Many relationship setup.

Group model

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'group_roles');
}
```

Role Model

```
public function groups()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group', 'group_roles');
}
```

GroupsController store method

```
public function store(Request $requests)
{
    $group = new Group;
    //$group->group_name = $requests->group_name;
    //$group->save();
    $group->create($requests->all());

    $group->roles()->sync($requests->input('roles'));


   Session::flash('success', $requests->group_name.' successfully added');
   return redirect('/settings/groups/groups');
```

}

The problem I have here is that when I call create method on the group model, it returns null, thus causing this `$group->roles()->sync($requests->input('roles'));` to fail. However, when I use the save method, it works flawlessly. Why doesn't the create work?

EDIT: if I use `create` it does insert the records into the database, but the problem is that it's not return `insertLastId`.

Answer (score 2):

In Group Model

```
public function groups()
{
    protected $fillable = ['group_name'] //add all the fillable fields
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Group', 'group_roles');
}
```

When `create()` method is used, it mass assigns all the values, so `protected $fillable = []`  should be used in that particular Model. see https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#mass-assignment

For Last Insert Id use db function instead because `create()` method doesn't return lastInsertId, it only returns `true` if data inserted successfully.

```
return DB::('table_name')->insertGetId([
    'group_name' => 'some name'
]);
```

Comment: I have `protected $fillable = ['group_name'];` already, right at the beginning of the model. The inserting works, but the problem is that its not returning `lastInsertId` despite the records being created in the database. I'm sorry if i gave little info

Comment: I've updated the answer. do let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I try not to use query builders as much as possible. I would rather just call `save` method in this case. if `create` only returns true, then why does this work https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/23 - skip to 1:00, he's using the `create` method.

Comment: why do you have `protected $fillable` inside that method?

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out. I changed this:

```
$group = new Group;
$group->create($requests->all());
```

To

```
$group = Group::create($requests->all())
```

Now create returns the last insert ID.

Comment: That is very useful , thanks  !